# Regular Expression: Mathematically vs. Programmatically

Tags: regex, semantics, formal-languages

Consider the following regular expressions:

1. 7+
2. (7)+

Does anyone that is very familiar with regular expression theory in Mathematics agree that the two regular expressions are semantically the same?

Comment: Just to clarify, what does the "vs. Programmatically" part of your question title mean?

Comment: @Greg: I'm guessing by "mathematically" OP meant regular languages in computational theory, and "programmatically" refers to regexp implementations (which recognizes more than regular languages).

Comment: @polygenelubricants: you guess it right :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, those two regular expressions are the same because they both recognize the same language. The fact that they are not written identically is just a notational issue.

Comment: This answer has a mathematical taste using terminologies drawn from Regular Expression theory.

Answer (score 4):

*Programmatically* (as in evaluated by the regular expression engine of a language) it only differs in the [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) resulting.

Other than that, they are the same. It is as writing `((7) + (1))` as opposed as `7 + 1`. They <strike>evaluate to</strike> are the same. (Yeah, mathematically speaking, regular languages doesn't evaluate to anything)

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "mathematically speaking, regular languages doesn't evaluate to anything". Regular expression mathematically evaluates to something for sure.

Comment: I'm not even sure about this one. Regular expression describe languages, that can then be parsed by a deterministic finite state machine. The output of such evaluation is either true or false, but the language doesn't have a value for itself (depends on the FSM you're parsing with). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Do they describe the same language? Yes. Do they mean the same thing to someone trying to interpret the language? No. The second one tells me that I should be more interested in the 7s.

Answer (score 0):

The second reduces to first. Do you agree that

```
 ab+
```

and

```
 a(b)+
```

and

```
 (ab)+
```

are semantically different?

Comment: Well, mathematically ab+ and a(b)+ are the same semantically.

Comment: Yes, but (ab)+ isn't, and that's why the brackets are important. If a minimalist example is chosen (as per the first two) then important differences are lost, that's why we needed the the third.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is the parens assign the enclosed pattern to a group so you can reference that little piece after it's been evaluated.

Comment: No, programmatically they differ more than that. Try to match both regular expressions in Python using re.findall() or in C using POSIX regex() to "777". The results are pretty much different.

Comment: Sorry, I think re.findall() is not a synonym for regex(). So, yes, programmatically they just differ in the grouping. But, I am interested in the Mathematics.